# api mail ru, узнать активные адреса

Tags: email, mail.ru

Здравствуйте, подскажите можно ли как то узнать активные адреса в mail.ru?

Мне нужно проверить, пользуются ли данным ящиком, например, последний вход или находится ли сейчас хозяин почты в онлайне.

Comment: можно проверить на уровне SMTP протокола. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email 

Реализация под php https://github.com/zytzagoo/smtp-validate-email

Comment: это проверка на существование адреса? мне нужно проверить пользуются ли данным ящиком, например последний вход или находится ли сейчас хозяин почты в онлайне.
наверно не правильно сформирован вопрос(

Comment: да, существует ли данный почтовый емейл.

Comment: а может и пароль получить?) кто будет шарить подобные данные о почтовом ящике? в мейл.ру можно только зайти на публичный мой мир профайл (если он есть) и там посмотреть https://my.mail.ru/mail/тачастьчтопередсобачкой

Comment: пароль не нужен) в той проге же это реализовано как то через api...

Comment: mail.ru api работает только после того, как юзеру пок-ся окошко с привилегиями, которые он разрешает приложению, подтверждая  доступ к своему аккаунту (как собственно и любые апи соц сетей). данные левого чувака нельзя вот просто так достать, чтобы там не писали фейковые сайты. уж точно не через апи)

Comment: 1. Напишите для чего вам это нужно. 2. Что значит в онлайне? Почта же не чат какой-то.

Comment: да для классического спама нужно. Это же как было бы прекрасно - быстро отфильтровать левые адреса!

Comment: ну mail.ru велик, надо пошерстить по разным проектам. есть Мой мир и там есть, но я вообще не захожу, а ящиков рабочих куча. по онлайну через Web-агент, заходите на любой проект авторизовавшись, справа-внизу будет, вот там в поиске людей и можно по емайлу узнать онлайн ли... а насчет автоматизации этого - это уже из области реверс-инжиниринга, те же кто боты пишут